# Can Apple Preview display the page size (dimensions in inches) of a PDF?

Tags: preview

If I open a PDF file using Adobe Acrobat, when I select **File** then **Properties**, I can see that the **Page Size** is 11 x 8.5 in.

Is there a way to access this information in Apple Preview?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

*Tools/Show Inspector* gives you this information and more. The shortcut is <kbd>⌘ command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>.

Comment: Is there a way to access this info from the command line. Like with pdfinfo on some other systems?

Comment: @phs, try `sips --getProperty all`. Perhaps it'd be best if you asked a separate question.