# Is there a way to convert dimensions to inches in OS X?

Tags: graphics

When I Get Info on a pdf or an image it gives me the dimensions in points, which is great. I need to know how big an image would be, at full size, in inches. Is there somewhere in OS X where that info is available? I found [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118579/can-apple-preview-display-the-page-size-dimensions-in-inches-of-a-pdf) where you can get that info via Preview, but having to open each file is painful.

Answer (score -1):

Open the file in Preview. Press `command` + I to open the Inspector window. You'll find the DPI of the image.

[image: General Info Tab of the Inspector]

You should get the required DPI in of the image.

Now launch Spotlight and divide image size in each dimension with the DPI. You should get your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but looking for something  in OS X where that info is available. Having to open each file in Preview is a bit painful with more than a few files.

Answer (score -1):

If you use the Preview to open that PDF or Pic then you can look up the original dimensions in Inches.

In Preview go to Tools- Adjust Size

By default it will be in pixels, but just click on the Units and select Inches.

Now it will show the actual size of the original image.

[image: Preview size]

Comment: He stated that he doesn't want to open files in Preview so this doesn't answer his question.